# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'threeRadius'. ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I am using ViewPagerIndicator at http://viewpagerindicator.com/.
And I am trying to change the space between circles. As it was recommended here [View pager indicator Jake Wharton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561859/view-pager-indicator-jake-wharton) I am using 'threeRadius'.

I do not if it the right place, but I put in to  node as additional attribute and I started getting this error now:

No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'threeRadius'.

Here is my configuration for CustomCirclePageIndicator:

```
<style name="CustomCirclePageIndicator">
        <item name="fillColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="pageColor">#2C3A46</item>
        <item name="strokeWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="radius">4dp</item>
        <item name="threeRadius">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

Could you please direct me to the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `threeRadius` in the attr.xml of the lib. You can take a look at the file [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/res/values/vpi__attrs.xml). Thats why you get this error message.

But there is a variable which is called `threeRadius` in the `CirclePageIndicator` class ([Link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java)) .

So you might change this value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for dummy question, I am very new in the domain. Do you mean I need to create the class, that extends CirclePageIndicator, and over there I will overwrite all functionality related to threeRadius? Like instead of final float threeRadius = mRadius * 3; I will write final float threeRadius = mRadius * 4; I have to try something like this?

Comment: The easy way is to change the value to threeRadius to a higher value in the CirclePageIndicator class.

Comment: I quickly went through the code and writing a Subclass might be a little hard.

Comment: But Android Studio does not let me do this. Here what I do: 1) I search for CirclePageIndicator class, 2) Android Studio finds it and opens, but in the top is says: 'Decompiled .class file', so I guess it takes it from the library and decompiles byte code to java 3) I try to edit this file, but it does not allow me, I guess it is read-only. Sorry, please do not jude me hard, I am very new here..

Comment: Ahh ok. Well yeah you could download the source code and add this project as module or you could create your own branch at github and use that in your project. The first one should be easier.

Comment: Thank you! You have been most helpful! So what did I do, I created CustomCirclePageIndicator java file, which extends CirclePageIndicator, copied in it all code from CirclePageIndicator, at the same time replacing everywhere CirclePageIndicator to CustomCirclePageIndicator. Then I changed float threeRadius = mRadius * 3; to float threeRadius = mRadius * 4; and in layout xml file referred to CustomCirclePageIndicator class.